# Assembly remains after unloading appdomain

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, appdomain

I have program, which creates `AppDomain`, loads assembly `prelude` within it and then unloads `AppDomain`. At the end program lists assemblies from default appdomain. It's simplified version of program. In next versions `prelude.dll` will be changed in runtime and continiously executed/unloaded with appdomain.

```
namespace appdomaintest
{

    class Program
    {
        static void log_assemblies(AppDomain domain)
        {
            foreach (var item in domain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{domain.FriendlyName} : {item.FullName}");
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                var prelude_domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("PreludeDomain#1", null, null);
                var asm = prelude_domain.Load(new System.Reflection.AssemblyName("prelude"));
                var myint = prelude_domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("prelude", "prelude.MyInt");
                myint.GetType().GetMethod("show").Invoke(myint, new object[0]);
                AppDomain.Unload(prelude_domain);
                Console.WriteLine("AppDomain was unloaded");
            }
            log_assemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is content of `prelude.dll`

```
public class MyInt : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public MyInt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"MyInt was constructed in {AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName}");
    }
    public void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"show in {AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName}");
    }
}
```

Here is output of program:

```
MyInt was constructed in PreludeDomain#1
show in PreludeDomain#1
AppDomain was unloaded
appdomaintest.exe : mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
appdomaintest.exe : appdomaintest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
appdomaintest.exe : prelude, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Unfortunately I discovered that my default appdomain contains `prelude.dll` assembly. As I understand it remains until end of execution of my program. Is there any way to prevent loading it  to default appdomain? In future versions `prelude.dll` will be repeatedly loaded/unloaded (its metadata also will be modified). That's why that behaviour is not suitable for my purposes.

It seems like for me that creation proxy object may lead to loading metadata to default domain. But how can I unload them?

Comment: Use IPC, I have used it for compiled in runtime razor pages from database. Then, after separate process becomes too big on RAM - kill it, start over. It is only approach currently.

Comment: @eocron it's heavy mechanics. Cost of creation/interruption/interconnection of native processes is heavy. In my case frequency of loading dynamic assembly is pretty big.

Comment: No one gives you guarantee. See here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-unload-an-application-domain You either go with process approach, or think about changing your approach of integrating third-party functionality through library (switching it to service). You don't need to start native process all the time, just start it, load this thing up, unload it, then shutdown process when it reach some limit on memory or count.

Answer (score 1):

It will remain, yes. There is no way around it, because this is just not possible which microsoft stated in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-unload-an-application-domain.

Use interprocess communication with another process. You can start process and load anything inside it, until it becomes bloated, after which you just kill it and start it over.

One benefit you get from this - no one will crash your app accidentally calling something unsafe in this library.

Comment: did You mean domain neutral assembly? But why my assembly is domain neutral?